# Convert array to object in javascript same as d3 output

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am trying to convert an array to an object same as d3.csv(...) output. I have a two dimensional array which looks like below;

```
0: {Biomass: null,Coal: null,Cogeneration: null,Gas: 42,Geothermal: null
country: "AFG"}
1: {Biomass: null,Coal: 20,Cogeneration: null,Gas: 10,Geothermal: null
country: "AOL"}
2: {Biomass: null,Coal: 10,Cogeneration: null,Gas: 30,Geothermal: null
country: "GER"}
```

what I want is to have the same output as d3.csv(...)
I tried to reduce and use below, but couldn't figure out how to convert the array into one object which the output should look like below

```
{Biomass: null,Coal: null,Cogeneration: null,Gas: 42,Geothermal: null
country: "AFG"}
{Biomass: null,Coal: 20,Cogeneration: null,Gas: 10,Geothermal: null
country: "AOL"}
{Biomass: null,Coal: 10,Cogeneration: null,Gas: 30,Geothermal: null
country: "GER"}
```

code I have tried

```
//output is the array
var o = {};
output.forEach((e, i) => {
   return o[i] = e;
});
console.log(o);
```

using reduce, can only convert first row

```
 const f = output.reduce((obj, item) => {
        obj[item.id] = item
        return obj
    });
    console.log(f);
```

how to convert array same as d3.csv(...) output?
A reference to what I am looking to convert array into [data.csv](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051) at the bottom of the page in data section.

Comment: I assume you have an array of objects, but what exactly is the second one? it is not a valid format in js

Comment: the 2nd one is the output of d3.csv(...) {console.log(data);} which I want to have the same.

Comment: ^----- *"the 2nd one is the output of d3.csv(...)"*... no, it's not. The output of `d3.csv` is an **array** of objects. And @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz is correct, that's not a valid JavaScript. In short, you already have what you're asking. Also, just as an explanation, you're running that `console.log` inside the row function, which will be called to **each row** in the CSV... hence the console showing separate objects (and `data` is not the whole data, but just each row).

Answer (score 0):

Just use d3

```js
const arr = [{Biomass: null, Coal: 20}, {Biomass: 1e2, Coal: 10}];
console.log(
  d3.csvFormat(arr)
);
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-dsv.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If by 2-dimensional array you mean it’s an object where the keys are integers and the values are the data objects you’re interested in, you can use that object’s `myObject.values()` method. Or, to ensure compatibility with older browsers, `d3.values(myObject)`.